# Is $\operatorname{diam}(A\cap B)=\operatorname{diam}(\overline{A}\cap B)$ true when $B$ is a ball?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a normed space, and let $B$ be the closed unit ball. Let $A$ be any subset of $X$ such that $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$.

> Is it true that $\operatorname{diam}(A\cap B)=\operatorname{diam}(\overline{A}\cap B)$?

I proved that the equality holds if $B$ is the open unit ball. For if $x\in \overline{A}\cap B$ when $B$ is the open unit ball, then $\left\|{x}\right\|<1$ and we can find a sequence $(x_n)\subseteq A$ with $\left\|{x_n}\right\|<1$ converging to $x$. This gives an obvious upper bound for any $d(x,y)$ with $x,y\in \overline{A}\cap B$.

But the same thing can't be done when $B$ is the closed unit ball, because if $\left\|{x}\right\|\le 1$, we can't guarantee that there is a sequence contained in $B$ converging to $x$.

Is the statement false with the closed ball maybe?

Comment: What makes you say that "if $ \vert x \vert \leq 1 $, we can't guarantee that there is a sequence contained in $B$ converging to $x$."?

Comment: @shortmanikos Sorry, I guess I explained it poorly. If $x\in\overline{A}\cap B$, there is a sequence $(x_n)$ consisting of elements in $A$ converging to $x$. I would like $x_n$ to be in $B$ too. If $B$ is the open ball, at some $n$ we have that $x_n\in B$ , but if $B$ is the closed ball then not necessarily $x_n\in B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false. You can construct a counter-example in $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ if you carefully think about when the sequence $ x_n \to x $ is not inside $ B $.